# How does one right justify a dedication?

Tags: untagged

Below is an MWE. How may the dedication be justified so that it aligns with the right margin of the text?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{\textbf{\LARGE The Recursionist Theory of Something}}
\date{}
\dedication {\scriptsize To the memory of my teacher,  
\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots.\,.\,.,\\
and  to the sleepless nights these problems caused.}
\author{ Sapiens}



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but `\LARGE` does not take an argument. `\LARGE{The Recursionist Theory of Something}` should be `\LARGE The Recursionist Theory of Something` (although of course you should not have formatting such as `\LARGE` or `\textbf` in `\title` at all)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table 3.3 of the komascript manual, you find the defaults for the elements of the title.

For the title proper, `\usekomafont{disposition}` is the default, but you can change it at wish.

Similarly, the dedication uses `\Large` (and `\centering`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries\LARGE}
\setkomafont{dedication}{\footnotesize\raggedleft}

\title{The Recursionist Theory of Something}
\author{Sapiens}
\date{}
\dedication{%
  Dedicated to \\
  the masters of directing \\
  by which I mean \\
  John Ford, John Ford \\
  and John Ford
}



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]